# Visual Studio - Search through code for Chinese text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, chinese

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to search through code and stop at lines that contain Chinese characters?

Answer (score 13):

Search for Chinese characters using [regular expressions in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.140).aspx). The regular expression `[一-龥]` matches any Chinese character.

The regular expression `^.*[一-龥]` matches any line containing a Chinese character.

- `^` Anchor the match string to the beginning of a line
- `.*` Match any character zero or more times (wildcard *)
- `[a-f]` Match any character in a range of characters, for example, `[一-龥]` matches any character in the range of Chinese characters starting with the first Chinese character `一` and ending with the last Chinese character `龥`.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore lines that start with /* or //

Comment: Use this regex `^(?!/)(?!/\*).*[一-龥]` in Visual Studio to ignore lines that start with /* or // (which are often used to denote comments). It's an example of regex negative lookahead.